# Multiple instances of jQuery in an iframe and parent

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I have a page that has a link to jQuery and a couple plugins, mainly jqModal.
The page has multiple links that open modal windows.  The modal window uses an iframe to show its content, and inside the modal is a page that again links to jQuery and jqModal.  Everything seems to work alright until I close the modal and try to open another modal using the links on the parent page.

After closing the window, any subsequent clicks on modal links gives me an error saying jQuery ($) is not defined (specifically $("#" + name).jqm is not a function, where $('#name').jqm instantiates the modal window).

I've tried using jQuery.noConflict() but to no avail, as all the plugins use the same $ jQuery variable and the structure of the site doesn't allow for multiple variables to different instances of jQuery.

Is there any way to re-link jQuery after the modal window is closed so I can regain access to the other modal links?

Thanks

Comment: You need to post the code you are using...

Answer (score 0):

since jquery version 1.5 you can use the jQuery.sub() function to create multiple instance of jQuery.

Comment: I was kind of hoping I could have the content in the iframe to use the parent jQuery instance instead of having to create a new instance, since it seems once the child instance is closed, it dereferences the parent instance.

Comment: The iframe is a special object because, you can insert a complete html page (including the <html></html> container). So I don't want to exclude  that there are some troublemakers.

Comment: I've tried it in a div as well, instead of loading the content via iframe src attribute, I used jQuery's load method to insert the content into the div, still had the same problems.

Comment: then follow the advise of Cybernate and post some source code. That increases the liklyhood to help you.